# In Bootstrap Protocol, how does a client know if a hardware broadcast is intended for another BOOTP client on the same physical net?

Tags: bootstrap-protocol

When a bootp client receives a reply via hardware broadcast, how does it know whether the reply is intended for another BOOTP client on the same physical net?

Comment: My friend asked me this question  But  I don't know much about Bootstrap Protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Bootstrap Protocol (defined [here](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc951.txt)) says:

> The client should discard incoming
>   packets that: are not IP/UDPs addressed to the boot port; are not
>   BOOTREPLYs; do not match my IP address (if I know it) or my
>   hardware address; do not match my transaction id.  Otherwise we
>   have received a successful reply. 'yiaddr' will contain my IP
>   address, if I didnt know it before.

(the transaction ID discussed above is a field in the BOOTREQUEST packet which is assigned a number known by the sender of the request. the field is assigned a random number and it is assumed that there are almost no chance of collision)